# How to initialize google maps API in angular without using any directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to initalize google maps in the application I am writing, I am using the places api for some of the functionalities which is working fine,
Now I am trying to show a map on a page but the map never shows up. i do not get any error on the console when I use the following code.

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&libraries=places"></script>
```

**mapview.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MapViewController as mapctrl" ng-init="initialize()">
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">



<div id="map"></div>

</div>

<div ui-view></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**mapViewController.js**

```
(function(angular) {
    angular.module('myapp').controller('MapViewController', ['$state','$http','$stateParams','$window','$route','$document','$localStorage','$scope','$location', function($state,$http,$stateParams,$window,$route,$document,$localStorage,$scope,$location) {

      $scope.initialize = function(){
        console.log("log");
          var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 11,
              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
       };

      }]);
      })(angular)
```

I get the log message when the contoller is initialized but the map doesn't show on the page.
I would like to know how can I make it possible without using any directive.

Comment: That's weird, can you share you `app-module` code? Also, did you define `ng-app`? Also, did you give `height and width` to your `map id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to define `ng-app` on your html:

```
<html ng-app="mapApp">
 . . .
  <body ng-controller="MapController" ng-init="initMap()">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then to initialize correctly your map on JS:

```
angular.module('mapApp', []);

angular
  .module('mapApp')
  .controller('MapController', MapController);

  function MapController($scope){

    $scope.initMap = function() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 3,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.483, 16.084)
        });
    }

}
```

And give `height` and `width` to your id:

```
#map{
      height: 400px;
      width:  700px;
      border: 2px solid red;
 }
```

here you can find [A Plunker I made](http://plnkr.co/edit/4MegQD1KPGCqWXeV2pfb) which initializes a map without a directive.

Hope I've been helpful.

Comment: edit: I deleted `immediate (function {})();` It gives issues with `Controllers`.

Comment: How can I miss that, just the height and width and boom!

Comment: Happens. Glad you fixed that.

Comment: I got `Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined` error and I'm using angular 6.