# initMap is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

guys. Here is my problem:

I have added google maps API to my project, where I'm using AngularJs.
And got in console this issue:

```
Uncaught 
message: "initMap is not a function"
name: "InvalidValueError"
```

It is happening when the Google Map API is loaded then the initMap function is executed. If I don't have an initMap function, then the initMap is not a function error is generated. I understand it!

Then I`ve added global initMap function to my main js file and the problem has gone!

Plese, can someone explain to me why the problem has gone? And is it a right solution or not to add just simple global function initMap() ? Thank You!

Comment: You need to provide some code. Anyways, look at this answer of mine about initializing google maps with angularjs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469001/how-to-initialize-google-maps-api-in-angular-without-using-any-directives/39469258#39469258.

Answer (score 2):

It is declared as a callback of the API. As soon as it's loaded, the function is executed. Remove that part and you should be good.

```
<script
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```